# Apply all functions from a list in Scala

Tags: scala

Say, I have a class `MyFunc` that has a single method `def transform(rdd: RDD): RDD`. This class comes from the library, so I can't change it.

Now imagine I have a `List[MyFun]` that I want to apply on an `rdd` variable.
I could write it as:

```
def applyAll(myFuncs: List[MyFunc], rdd: RDD): RDD = {
  var mutableRef = rdd
  for (myFunc <- myFuncs) {
    mutableRef = myFunc.transform(mutableRef)
  }
  mutableRef
}
```

Scala's beauty comes from conciseness. Thus I'm looking for a way to apply all `MyFunc` in order in a concise manner.

Comment: `myFuncs.foldLeft(rdd)((r,f) => f(r))` ?

Comment: indeed, `myFuncs.foldLeft(rdd)(f(_._1))`.

Comment: If the Funcs were in reverse order (or order didn't matter) you could do this:`foldRight(rdd)(_(_))`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! It's missing the transform method so the final version would be: `myFuncs.foldLeft(rdd)((r,f) => f.transform(r))` or similar with Andy's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways for doing this, the easiest is as suggested in the comment is to use `foldLeft`. However you can still easily write it functionally using recursion without any mutation as follows,

```
 def applyAll(myFuncs: List[MyFunc], rdd: RDD): RDD = {

  @tailrec
  def applyOne(myFuncs: List[MyFunc],newRDD: RDD): RDD = myFuncs match {
  case h::t => applyOne(t, h.transform(newRDD))
  case Nil => newRDD
  }
  applyOne(myFuncs,rdd)
 }
```

`foldLeft` is great and you should use it, but it is very similar to what you were intially doing, ie it loops over the list and mutates a variable.